# Laravel Socialite Login validate

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a laravel project to login with socialite recently.

I have an deactivate account function for Admin. I have my codes to prevent my users to login if their status is 1 (which is deactivated) but these codes doesn't work with user who use socialite function to login.

My codes to prevent deactivate user to login as shown below.

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user){
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 0]))
    {
        if($user->role == 2)
        {   
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/users');
        }else{
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }
    }else{
        Auth::logout();
        return back()->with('error', 'Your account is deactivated.');
    }
}
```

Controller for socialite

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\SocialAccountService;
use Socialite;
use App\User;

class SocialAuthController extends Controller
{
public function FacebookRedirect()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function FacebookCallback(SocialAccountService $service)
{
    $fbUser = $service->FacebookCreateOrGetUser(Socialite::Driver('facebook')->user());
    auth()->login($fbUser);
    return redirect()->to('/');
    //$facebookUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    //$facebookFirstnameAccess = $facebookUser->user['first_name'];
    //echo $facebookFirstnameAccess;
    //dd($facebookUser);
}

public function GoogleRedirect()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}

public function GoogleCallback(SocialAccountService $service)
{
    $Guser = $service->GoogleCreateOrGetUser(Socialite::Driver('google')->user());
    auth()->login($Guser);
    //$googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    return redirect()->to('/');
    //$fName = $googleUser->firstname = $googleUser->user['name']['givenName'];
    //$lName = $googleUser->lastname = $googleUser->user['name']['familyName'];
    //echo $lName;
    //dd($googleUser);
}
}
```

Is there anywhere for me to prevent the user to login with socialite if I have deactivated their account?

Comment: can you please share the part of code with `socialite ` where you actually log in the user?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: I'm not sure the `auth()->login()` takes extra parameter but can't you check it like, `if($Guser->status == 0) { auth()->login($Guser);}` 
`else{ // do something else}`